# Is there an operator or more elegant way of writing an if-statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am still in the beginning stages of learning and obviously trying to shorten instances like this, where I have many if conditionals to go through. Just wondering how someone more experienced tackles this? I have tried with 'or' and 'and' operators, and I try to nest my statements where I see I can, but generally it still feels quite clumsy.
This bit of code was part of a date-validator using regex for How To Automate The Boring Stuff, I don't have a else statement as there is more conditionals in the full code. Is there a better way or am I over complicating it?

```
    if month == 4 and day == 31:
            print("Invalid date found in text")
            return False
    elif month == 6 and day == 31:
            print("Invalid date found in text")
            return False
    elif month == 9 and day == 31:
            print("Invalid date found in text")
            return False
    elif month == 11 and day == 31:
            print("Invalid date found in text")
            return False
```

Comment: A typical newcomer mistake is to try to implement the complexity of dates and times manually. There are libraries for that. In your case, feed the date into a `datetime.date()` and if it does not raise an error, it's fine.

Comment: Using `datetime` is certainly the right answer - but you could definitely shorten the code you showed: `if month in (4, 6, 9, 11) and day == 31:` for example.

Comment: Yeah I see that a questions about time probably wasn't the best, my bad, thank you all for your time! And jasonharper, this solved my particular problem, thank you, I wasn't able to get the in operator to work for some reason at first.

Comment: For future reference: if the question is purely about coding style, [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be a more suitable site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said, you want to use a library to deal with dates.  But for a case like yours, you could do this:

```
    illegal_dates = [(4,31), (6,31), (9,31), (11,31)]
    if (month, day) in illegal_dates:
            print("Invalid date found in text")
            return False
```

When you find yourself being repetitive, you can sometimes make an ad-hoc list of values and loop through them.  In your case, we don't even need a for loop, we can just check if the tuple is in the list.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like this! Will save this for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
import datetime
try :
    datetime.datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day))
except ValueError :
    print("Invalid date found in text")
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have specified, obviously the datetime module is the smartest for working with dates, this particular assignment was for learning regex, so we had to go about it that way. So of course the code if bulkier than it needs to be as is, but I was just looking for a more general answer in cases like this, if I was missing something, like a better use of an operator. 

But thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, the DateTime library is the best way to check the correctness of date (as it handles various edge scenarios like Feb has 28 days, etc.), but if it is just about writing above piece with brevity, one can try following:

```
month_invalid = True if (month in [4,6,9,11]) else False
day_invalid = True if day==31 else False
if month_invalid or day_invalid:
    return false
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a common expression in a sequence of if statements, you can often factor them out so it can be an outer expression controlling a block, for example:

```
if (day == 31) and (month in (4,6,9,11)):
    print("Invalid date found in text")
    return False
```

But for checking for ranges with obvious indexes, you would probably use (ignoring leapyear):

```
 maxdays = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
 if day > maxdays[month-1]:
     print("Invalid date found in text")
     return False
```